# Iterative matrix system - Convergence

Tags: matrices, convergence-divergence, normed-spaces

Let $k = 0, 1 \dotsc,$ and consider the following system
\begin{align*} 
\mathbf{u}^{(0)} &:= \mathbf{f}, \\ 
\mathbf{u}^{(k+1)} &:= \mathbf{H}\mathbf{u}^{(k)}.
\end{align*}
where $\mathbf{H} \in \mathbb{R}^{d \times d}$ is a symmetric Matrix such that $h_{ij} \geq 0$ and the sum of each row is equal to $1$: $\sum_{j=1}^{d} h_{ij} = 1$ for all $i$.

Assume that $\rho(\mathbf{H}) = \max |\lambda_i| = 1$ the biggest eigenvalue of $\mathbf{H}$. Then $\lim_{k \to \infty} \mathbf{u}^{(k)} = \mu \mathbf{1}$ where $\mu = \sum_{j=1}^{d} \frac{1}{d} f_j$.

*Attempt:* Because of symmetry, the columns of $\mathbf{H}$ also sum to $1$ and clearly also $\mathbf{H} \cdot \mathbf{1} = \mathbf{1}$ eigenvector and also $\mathbf{H}^k \cdot \mathbf{1} = \mathbf{1}$. Taking the two-norm on $\mathbb{R}^{d}$, we have
\begin{align*} 
||\mathbf{u}^{(k)} - \mu \mathbf{1}||_2 &=  ||\mathbf{H}^k \cdot \mathbf{f} - \mathbf{H}^k \cdot  (\mu  \mathbf{1})||_2 \\[5 pt]
&\leq  ||\mathbf{H}^k||_{2}  \ ||\mathbf{f} - \mu  \mathbf{1}||_2 \\[5 pt]
&= \rho(\mathbf{H}) \ ||\mathbf{f} - \mu  \mathbf{1}||_2 = ||\mathbf{f} - \mu  \mathbf{1}||_2.
\end{align*}
I am not really sure what to conclude further. Also, component-wise, we have $$ |\mathbf{u}_i^{(k)} - \sum_{j=1}^{d} \frac{1}{d} f_j| \leq |\mathbf{u}_i^{(k)}| + f_{max} \leq 2 f_{max},$$
where $f_{max} = ||\mathbf{f}||_{\infty}$ is maximum component of $\mathbf{f}$ and the inequality follows because $|\mathbf{u}_{max}^{(k)}| \leq |\mathbf{u}_{max}^{(k-1)}|.$

Comment: Assuming $\mathbf{1}$ is a vector of ones, this doesn't seem to be true unless we assume $h_{ij} > 0$ (the inequality is strict). Otherwise, consider $H = I$, and you see that $\mathbf{u}^{(k)} = \mathbf{f}$ for all $k$.

Comment: Exactly, the question states non-negative, which I assume is greater than or equal $0$. How can I go about proving this, when the inequality is strict?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As noted in the comments, this assertion is not true if we only require that the entries be non-negative, just by taking $\mathbf{H} = \mathbf{I}_d$.

The easiest way to prove this assertion whenever $\mathbf{H}$ is strictly positive (or by extension, when it is non-negative and irreducible) is by using the [Perron-Frobenius Theorem](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Perron%E2%80%93Frobenius_theorem), which asserts that the eigenvalue of greatest magnitude (call it $\rho$) has an eigenspace that is one-dimensional, i.e. there is only one non-zero linearly independent vector $\mathbf{v}$ such that $\mathbf{H} \mathbf{v} = \rho \mathbf{v}$. It further asserts that all the other eigenvalues of $\mathbf{H}$ are *strictly smaller* than $\rho$ in magnitude. From the given information about $\mathbf{H}$, we can see that $\rho = 1$ and the corresponding eigenvector is $\mathbf{1}$.

Since in addition $\mathbf{H}$ is symmetric, we know from the Spectral Theorem that it admits an orthonormal basis of eigenvectors, of which $\mathbf{v}_1 = \frac{1}{\sqrt d} \mathbf{1}$ is one. Let this basis of eigenvectors be $\{\mathbf{v}_1, \mathbf{v}_2, \cdots, \mathbf{v}_d\}$, with corresponding eigenvalues $\lambda_1, \cdots, \lambda_d$. Then $\mathbf{f}$ can be written as a linear combination of these eigenvectors:
$$\mathbf{f} = c_1 \mathbf{v}_1 + c_2 \mathbf{v}_2 + \cdots + c_d \mathbf{v}_d$$
and note that $c_1 = \langle \mathbf{f}, \mathbf{v}_1 \rangle = \frac{1}{\sqrt d} \sum_{j = 1}^d f_j = \mu \sqrt{d}$ (why?). So we have that
$$\mathbf{H}^k \mathbf{f} = c_1 \lambda_1^k \mathbf{v}_1 + c_2 \lambda_2^k \mathbf{v}_2 +  \cdots + c_1 \lambda_d^k \mathbf{v}_d = \mu \mathbf{1} + c_2 \lambda_2^k \mathbf{v}_2 +  \cdots + c_1 \lambda_d^k \mathbf{v}_d$$
and you can see that
$$\| \mathbf{H}^k \mathbf{f} - \mu \mathbf{1}\| = \|c_2 \lambda_2^k \mathbf{v}_2 +  \cdots + c_1 \lambda_d^k \mathbf{v}_d\| \leq |c_2| \cdot |\lambda_2|^k + \cdots + |c_d| \cdot |\lambda_d|^k$$
(by the triangle inequality) and thus tends to zero as $k \to \infty$. This concludes the proof. $\square$

Comment: very helpful answer, thanks!